# phantomjs can't render font-family

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, phantomjs

When I converted HTML pages to images (png) with `phantomjs`, the font-family on pictures did not render. The font-family is Arial. My platform is Linux (Ubuntu). My linux has Arial in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` and `/usr/share/fonts/type1`.

Answer (score 0):

haha ,I have solved this question, accroding to this issue https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13984  and https://medium.com/@juddstiffiii/google-phantomjs-fonts-puts-this-article-at-the-top-7ca7e8544eaf，
hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since this question was asked but I ran into the same Issue. i.e. Arial was not rendering propperly when trying to take screenshots via PhantomJS.

I found my solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/651441/how-to-install-arial-font-and-other-windows-fonts-in-ubuntu

For the sake of simplycity I will repeat it, however, its [barsmaga's](https://askubuntu.com/users/1071409/barsmaga) work:

```
echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

If this does not work then try running with `--reinstall`:
`apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer --reinstall`

My specs for the record:

```
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

And as some extended context:
I was trying to take screenshots of `huxtable` html tables with `webshot` in `R statistics`.